# Can a CSS pixel be a fraction?

Tags: css, w3c

Can a CSS `px` be a fraction? Is it allowed by the standards? And if so, do the major browsers support it?

Let's back the answers up with documentation, folks.

Comment: @MetalFrog this question originates from a discussion at work :-)

Comment: Ironically, I recently had to use a fractional pixel to get a jQuery UI sortable grid to layout properly. When the margin on the placeholder was the same as or one pixel smaller than the margin on the surrounding items, the grid would shift all over the place when dragging. The only fix (and a cross-browser one at that!) was to decrease the placeholder's margin by 0.5px. Then, everything worked fine. Whether it's spec or not is mostly pedantic, you have to do what you have to do at the end of the day.

Comment: Are there rules about how a line of less than 1px should be rendered by the broweser? I have many pages (Word documents converted to HTML) where table borders have width corresponding to a fraction of a pixel. These display as 1px in IE and firefox but the border is not visible at all inside chrome

Comment: Was your original question regarding fractions or decimals?  A fraction would be 1/3, whereas a decimal would be .33 (repeating).  Mathematically, there's a difference, and if anything cares about the technicalities of math, it's computers.

Comment: Non-duplicate, but related - a discussion of fractional pixels being respected by rendering:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Yes, you can specify fractional pixels. As this has been part of CSS since the very first version, it should be well supported by any browser that supports CSS at all.

Reference: [CSS 2.1: 4.3.2 Lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#length-units)

> "The format of a length value (denoted by <length> in this
>   specification) is a <number> (with or without a decimal point)
>   immediately followed by a unit identifier (e.g., px, em, etc.)."

When the elements are displayed on the screen, most browsers will naturally round the position to the nearest pixel when using 100% zoom level. On higher zoom levels you will notice that fractional pixel values are recognized.

Comment: Do you have some documentation that supports the answer?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: I just added that. :)

Comment: The problem is, different browsers round differently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5587820/405015

Comment: Found an interesting blog on the subject: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Comment: To clarify, a fraction would be 1/3, whereas a decimal would be .33 (repeating).  I acknowledge that it's partly semantics (not to a math major, it's not), but the correct answer is that CSS does not support fractions or fractional pixels.  It does, however, support decimal pixel values.

Comment: @Mike: The term fraction can be used in different ways, just like the term decimal that can either specify a number having a fractional part or a number expressed in base ten.

Comment: Whereas pixel fractions have no affect on browser rendering, they may have significant effect on printer output

Comment: I understand that browsers round differently, and thus fractional pixels will be treated differently across different browsers. However, I recently tested this and got different results using the **same** browser (and version!) but on 2 different Mac devices. What could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: A different PPI (pixels per inch) value of the screens of those mac devices.